# How to combine tuples in list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Combining tuples in list of tuples

```
test_list = [([1, 2, 3], 'gfg'), ([5, 4, 3], 'cs')]
```

How to get this output:

```
[(1, 'gfg'), (2, 'gfg'), (3, 'gfg'), (5, 'cs'), (4, 'cs'), (3, 'cs')]
```

Comment: Hello. Typically when posting your questions here, it would be helpful both for yourself and the reader if the attempt you made was provided in order to understand where your misunderstanding and difficulties are. It would allow the person answering your question to highlight where your mistakes are to further your understanding and learning, followed by providing a more relevant answer. Could you please provide your code and explain where you are having difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Just to go into a bit more detail about how to do this with list comprehensions and explain what they are and how they work...

To begin with, here's a fairly long-winded way of achieving what you want:

```py
test_list = [([1, 2, 3], 'gfg'), ([5, 4, 3], 'cs')]

result = []  # set up empty list to hold the result
for group in test_list:  # loop through each 'group' in your list
    (numbers, text) = group  # unpack into the list of numbers and the text string
    for n in numbers:  # loop through the numbers
        result.append((n, text))  # add the (number, text) tuple to the result list

print(result)
# [(1, 'gfg'), (2, 'gfg'), (3, 'gfg'), (5, 'cs'), (4, 'cs'), (3, 'cs')]
```

So we've achieved the result using two `for` loops, one nested inside the other.

But there's a really neat Python construct called a **list comprehension** which lets you do this kind of loop in just one line.

Using an example with just a single loop:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

doubles = []
for n in numbers:
    doubles.append(n * 2)

print(doubles)
# [2, 4, 6]
```

We can re-write this as the following list comprehension:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

doubles = [n * 2 for n in numbers]

print(doubles)
# [2, 4, 6]
```

A list comprehension is of the form:

`result = [<expression> for item in iterable]`

which is equivalent to:

```py
result = []
for item in iterable:
    result.append(<expression>)
```

where `<expression>` is something involving `item`.

You can also nest list comprehensions like you can nest `for` loops. Going back to our original problem, we need to first change it so that we 'unpack' `group` into `numbers` and `text` directly when we set up the `for` loop:

```py
result = []
for (numbers, text) in test_list:
    for n in numbers:
        result.append((n, text))
```

Now imagine dragging the `for` loops off to the right until we can line them all up:

```py
result = []
for (numbers, text) in test_list:
                                   for n in numbers:
                                                      result.append((n, text))
```

and then put the expression (i.e. `(n, text)`) at the left:

```py
result = [(n, text) for (numbers, text) in test_list for n in numbers]
```

List comprehensions may seem strange at first (especially if you're jumping straight into a double list comprehension!), but one you've got your head around how they work, they are really neat and can be very powerful! There are also similar *set* comprehensions and *dictionary* comprehensions. Read more here: https://dbader.org/blog/list-dict-set-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Thank You all for your help. I got my output. Thanks for your amazing explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested list comprehensions:

```
test_list = [([1, 2, 3], 'gfg'), ([5, 4, 3], 'cs')]

result = [(z, y) for x, y in test_list for z in x]
#          z = numbers in the lists inside the tuples
#          x = the lists inside the tuples
#          y = the strings inside the tuples

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'gfg'), (2, 'gfg'), (3, 'gfg'), (5, 'cs'), (4, 'cs'),(3, 'cs')]
```

---

`result = [(z, y) for x, y in test_list for z in x]` is the list comprehension version for:

```
result = []
for x, y in test_list:
    for z in x:
        result.append((z,y))
```

Comment: Hi Mr Geek. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you please explain me the code :result = [(z, y) for x, y in test_list for z in x]

Comment: It's the list comprehension version of `result = []; for x,y in test_list: for z in x: result.append((z,y))`.